# DataError value too long for type character varying(100)

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models, cloudinary

I need to make changes to my profiles object at the admin site in Django, but when I click save, I get the error DataError at /admin/profiles/profiles/31/change/ value too long for type character varying(100). The weird thing is, it worked when I made changes to the same field locally, but when I deployed to Heroku, it gave me the 'DataError'. My image url is the only long string in my object. Side note, I am still using sqlite3 with Heroku because the data is very small.

```
Currently: http://res.cloudinary.com/firslovetema/image/upload/v1568570093/ypqiiwg5eq5uyd7oie6g
```

I have tried setting the max_length to 512. it still did not work.

my models.py file:

```
   from django.db import models
   from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField

class profiles(models.Model):
     firstname = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') #max_length=120
     lastname = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
     gender = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
     dob = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
     callNumber = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
     whatsappNumber = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
     ministry = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
     centre = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
     campus = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
     hostel_address = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
     city = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
     qualification = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
     profession = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
     maritalStatus = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
     bacenta = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
     layschool = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
     imagefile = CloudinaryField('image', null=True, max_length=512, blank=True)


 def __str__(self):
    return str(self.imagefile)
```

Full error log:

```
DataError at /admin/profiles/profiles/31/change/
value too long for type character varying(100)
   Request Method:  POST
   Request URL: https://ewuradjango.herokuapp.com/admin/profiles/profiles/31/change/
   Django Version:  2.2.3
   Exception Type:  DataError
   Exception Value: 
   value too long for type character varying(100)
   Exception Location:  /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute, line 84
   Python Executable:   /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
   Python Version:  3.7.1
   Python Path: 
   ['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
   '/app',
   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python37.zip',
   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7',
   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
   '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 17 Sep 2019 11:31:39 +0000
```

Comment: Did you make and ran migrations after you have set it to 512, etc.?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes I did

Comment: https://help.heroku.com/UFTJ43FM/how-do-i-resolve-value-too-long-for-type-character-varying-errors-in-heroku-connect - this link helps to understand the problem better

Comment: I just found out in the full error log that the 'imagefile' url returns an empty string, it works when i select a new photo, but what I am confused about is that i see a 'Current' image url on the admin site and it only works when i change the picture. My question is, why is it not picking the current image url string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django admin site does not pick current image URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57996831/django-admin-site-does-not-pick-current-image-url)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, For some reason running:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

was not applying the migrations locally. Read somewhere that you need to be specific with the python version you were running with. Thus I realized running:

```
heroku run python3 manage.py migrate
```

did not only generate and apply the migrations locally but also allowed the image file field to be created thus resolving the error above.