# Django admin site does not pick current image URL

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models, cloudinary

I am trying to edit the fields of one of my objects in the Django admin site, I also have a Cloudinary image field in my model. The issue is, anytime I try to make an edit to one of the `CharField`s of my object, I get the error:

```
value too long for type character varying(100)
```

which I later found out that every time I finish my edits and I am trying to save, it looks for a new image to replace the current image of my `imagefile` even though I did not touch my `imagefile`, thus it returns an empty image URL string like this:

[image]

But the current image URLworks fine and displays when clicked like this:

[image]

I just want to know if I am doing something wrong, why does it look for a new image URL every time I click save?

This is my `models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField

class profiles(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') #max_length=120
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
    callNumber = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
    whatsappNumber = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
    ministry = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
    centre = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
    campus = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
    hostel_address = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
    maritalStatus = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
    bacenta = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
    layschool = models.CharField(max_length=120, default = 'null') 
    imagefile = CloudinaryField('image', max_length=512, null=False,  default = 
 'https://res.cloudinary.com/firslovetema/image/upload/v1566807474/h1psyutzptxlnhuk8uyr.png')



def __str__(self):
    return str(self.imagefile)
```

This is a follow up question to my previous question which can be found here:

[value too long for type character varying(100)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57973619/dataerror-value-too-long-for-type-character-varying100)

Comment: Are you sure you've generated and applied migrations to create the `imagefile` field? The Cloudinary library [hard-coded `max_length` to 255](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/ddba6c3182022af9d1428280535030c32efd34a7/cloudinary/models.py#L52), so (a) your `max_length=512` doesn't do anything and (b) you shouldn't be seeing an error about `VARCHAR(100)` on that field. Remember, you only need to `makemigrations` locally, but after you commit the migration files you must `migrate` on Heroku.

Comment: @Chris okay, how do I migrate on Heroku?

Comment: You've probably done this at least once, since your database appears not to be empty: `heroku run python manage.py migrate`, after pushing whatever commits contain the migration files.

Comment: Thank you! it worked @Chris

Answer (score 2):

Django saves all attributes, not just the ones you've changed, when you save an object.

The Cloudinary library [hard-codes `max_length` to 255](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/ddba6c3182022af9d1428280535030c32efd34a7/cloudinary/models.py#L52), so

- your `max_length=512` doesn't do anything, and
- you shouldn't be seeing an error about `VARCHAR(100)` on that field.

Are you sure that all of your migrations have been applied on Heroku? Try running

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```